# Should I use Django for simple website?

Tags: django, python-3.x, web-development-server

I have been learning the Django framework for the last few weeks and I need to create a simple website for a dentist. The site just needs to have a few pages with flat data.
I was wondering whether using Django for this sort of project is good?
I am also not sure whether I need any applications for this except a contact form, the site will mostly contain only views and templates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. And more specifically, what not to ask: [help/dont-ask]

Comment: Recommendations of software for use cases aren't really what Stack Overflow is for. That said, while Django will do what you want, I'd probably go for an off the shelf content management system for that use case rather than a framework unless it needs a fair amount of custom functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use frameworks like Django (RoR, Flask, Express), because it helps to make a **web application** easily (scaffolding).

You don't need to reinvent the wheel to make something simple.

By the way, for only-static content 2-3 pages I would recommend do not use programming tools. Use generators like Tilda / Wix or something similar to it.

Comment: If I would still go for Django is it good in this case? I want to get more experience in this framework.

Comment: I suppose it is overkill. If you want to get a nice experience try to build this site with application form for clients to make an appointment to the dentist, it will require database management and will be suitable for an ORM Framework (like Django) usage.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are blatantly off-topic. See [answer] for details. Also, don't use profanity, even if with characters r\*m\*ved.